# Symfony: Extending the original AppBundle template files

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig

I'm having a bundle `Acme/Bundle/BlogBundle` within this structure:

```
app/...
app/Resources/views/base.html.twig
bin/...
Acme/Bundle/BlogBundle/Resources/views/Default/blog.html.twig
src/...
src/AppBundle/...
```

Within the `blog.html.twig` I want to extend the `base.html.twig` off initially and automatically generated `AppBundle`.

This is my best guess:

```
{% extends '@AppBundle/base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
test
{% endblock body %}
```

I tried a few other syntaxes but none seem to work. So, how to you inter-reference template files with the ov `AppBundle` folder?

Docs (which didn't help me): http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/namespaced_paths.html

Comment: try `{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}` ?

Comment: Btw, for extend from `'@App/base.html.twig'` it should be here: `src/AppBundle/Resources/views/base.html.twig`

Comment: and `@AppBundle/...` should be `@App/...` i.e without `Bundle` suffix.

Comment: @yceruto `{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}` works, although your second amd third comment don't make sense for me, could you explain? Moreover could you explain, why no referencing is needed?

Comment: Yep, I'll post an answer explaining this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `TwigBundle` installed in your app (by default in SE) and `AppBundle`, you have these Twig's paths automatically registered (in this order):

```
# config.yml
twig:
    paths:
        # behind the scenes!!
        src/AppBundle/Resources/views: App     # without Bundle suffix (convention)
        app/Resources/views: ~                 # %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/views
```

It means that `App` namespace (`@App` as Twig's convention) is used to refer to any template located in `src/AppBundle/Resources/views` exclusively:

```
'(@App === src/AppBundle/Resources/views)/base.html.twig'
```

For `~` symbol (that represents `null` in PHP) the `app/Resources/views` path is used when none namespace is referenced to load some template:

```
'(null === app/Resources/views/)base.html.twig'
```

Hence `{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}` is needed (in your case) if it *live* in `app/Resources/views` directory.